# Should I reply to unsolicited recruitment emails?

Tags: career-development, internship

As a university student with 4 month internship experience in telecommunication corp before, I received an email from one of the mobile & wireless related company (I did submit my resume to them before) saying I have met all sorts of pre-selection requirements and my resume has been proceeded to the hiring manager in charge of this position.

I am interested in this position and I was wondering if I should reply this email now?

Comment: Yes. You lose nothing by asking for details.

Comment: Was this an unsolicited email or did they get your info from a student internship listing where students know there info will be shared?

Comment: Unsolicited or unexpected? If you've got your resume out in circulation through channels where such a company might read it, you should except to get such emails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you've submitted or posted your resume anywhere that you suspect could have led to this company reviewing it, then the best course of action here would be to reply to the email thanking the company for their interest, and asking for more information regarding the position (and the company, if you are unfamiliar with it, although some basic internet research could fill you in). Since this was unsolicited/unexpected, I wouldn't provide any personal information until you've confirmed that it is a legitimate company and is actually interested in you.

If you *haven't* submitted or posted your resume anywhere, and are unsure how the company would have found it, this could potentially be a phishing scam. *Do not send any personal information*. If it doesn't seem like something you'd be interested in, and doesn't match up with your *actual* resume at all, ignore it. If it seems like they may have actually seen your resume, I recommend the same course of action as above, but with a bit more caution, and possibly a question about how they found you/your resume.

Answer (score 7):

What is being asked of you at this point?  If it is just an email confirming you are willing to go forward with the process then you have little risk.

On the other hand if it is looking for Personally Identifiable Information then I would be hesitant.  If the company really has your resume then they should already have a significant amount of this and should not need you to confirm it over email.  If this is a legitimate offer then your inquiries into the company, so long as they are courteous, should not be unexpected.  You should be able to get a website to check out the company, a phone number of someone you can call and talk to in person.  I prefer to get that number then call the general number and get the receptionist to confirm the number is correct for the person.

DO NOT FALL FOR FEAR OF LOSS TACTICS!

There is a sales tactic that is used by scammers to make you think that if you ask any questions that you will lose out.  If this is a real offer then you should be able to get information on it with little effort.  At this point the company has decided to persue you and should not be afraid of any questions.  Be courteous and polite but Questions like where is the position located, what will the position entail, should be answered.  It may be that the recruiter does not have specifics, that may be OK.  But when they start getting offended by common questions red flags pop up for me.